# Removing duplicates due to order by fields from a related model

Tags: django, django-queryset, django-orm

I have 2 different models in the same app

```
class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250, unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=50)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=500)

class Chapter(models.Model):
    book = models.ForeignKey(Book,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    num = models.PositiveIntegerField(verbose_name="Chapter Number")
    rdate = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name="Release Date", default=timezone.now)
```

What I want to do is get all books ordered by descending of release date `rdate`
What I tried is:

`Book.objects.all().order_by('-chapter__rdate').distinct()`

Some duplicates were found in result, I only had 2 books added, so only 1 book was duplicated. The result was something like this: Book1, Book2, Book2

I have already seen the note from [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.distinct), and im using SQLite.
By using values(), I won't be able to call get_absolute_url() and some other methods that I want to call so using values() is out of question.

Next I tried to annotate the Chapter rdate into Book query like this 
`Book.objects.all().annotate(bdate=ExpressionWrapper(F('chapter__rdate'), output_field=DateTimeField())).order_by('-bdate').distinct()`

Still ended in the same result. I'm totally lost, please need help. I probably won't change to PostgreSQL now, but I might use it when I deploy the app, so I want both SQLite version and PostgreSQL version solutions for this if at all possible. SQLite solution is absolutely necessary for me since it's easy to use in development.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Worked after I tried this :

`Book.objects.all().annotate(ch_date=Max('chapter__rdate')).order_by('-ch_date')`

Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
Chapter.objects.values('book__title').distinct()
```

This will return books which have at least one chapter.

Comment: Yeah I wont be able to still call methods like get_absolute_url and others so no use.

Comment: it's another topic, not related to `order`. look at :https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/instances/#get-absolute-url

Answer (score 1):

You should try like below:

```
Book.objects.all().order_by('-chapter__rdate').distinct('chapter__rdate')
```

This will give you a different `chapter_rdate`.

Comment: It's throw `django.db.utils.NotSupportedError: DISTINCT ON fields is not supported by this database backend
` Can you check this?

Comment: Please try after removing '-' from your clause.

Book.objects.all().order_by('chapter__rdate').distinct('chapter__rdate')

please share errors if still, it is not working.